# Como usar uma Variavel criada no Then() fora da função

Tags: javascript, react

Gostaria de saber como uso o valor retornado dentro da minha arrow function que estou salvando com ipv4, fora da função
pois quando dou o console.log dentro da função, me retorna o resultado certo, quando coloco pra fora da função me retorna undefined.

```
let ipv4;

publicIp().then(value => {
    ipv4 = value
    console.log(ipv4)// retorna o valor da promise
    return ipv4
})

publicIp()

console.log(ipv4)// retorna undefined
```

Comment: Pelo que vi nas respostas, nao me ajuda em muita coisa, pois nao tem uma resolução de como posso usar o valor obtido na variavel fora da função, e é disso que eu preciso

Comment: A execução desse método é assincrona, né? Então tu deverias esperar a execução completa antes de tentar ler (imprimir no console) o valor da variável. Dá uma lida sobre `Promise`...

Comment: a publicIp é uma função que esta vindo de uma biblioteca do react q eu achei, o retorno dela é uma promise,  o resultado da promise é o IP na qual eu quero salvar para utilizar, achei a forma de acessar o resultado da promise usando o Then(), porem nao estou conseguindo salvar ele, acho que agora ficou mais claro a minha duvida.
pois no console.log ele me retorna o IP corretamente dentro da função Then(), então creio que o assinc e await ja estao sendo executados pela propria lib
Nome da lib: public-ip

Comment: O que talvez não esteja claro pra você é que o console.log do final do seu código executa ANTES da função que é passada ao then. Por isso não funciona assim como você quer. Você precisa usar o valor de dentro do then, pra garantir que ele esteja disponível. Você pode, por exemplo, criar uma função que recebe o valor e faz o que você precisa, e chamar essa função passando o valor de dentro do then.

Comment: @bfavaretto Seria algo do tipo??

publicIp().then(value => {
function render(){
    ipv4 = value
    console.log(ipv4)
    return ipv4}
})

Comment: @JoãoVictorValentim, leia com atenção a resposta da pergunta indicada no primeiro comentário.

Comment: @JoãoVictorValentim Não, seria algo assim: `publicIp().then(funcaoQueVaiUsarOValor)`. E aí você declara fora do then a função como `funcaoQueVaiUsarOValor(valor) {...}`.